# Convert normal Java Array or ArrayList to Json Array in android

Tags: java, android, json

Is there any way to convert a normal Java array or `ArrayList` to a Json Array in Android to pass the JSON object to a webservice?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you want or need to work with a Java array then you can always use the `java.util.Arrays` utility classes' static [`asList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method to convert your array to a `List`.

Something along those lines should work.

```
String mStringArray[] = { "String1", "String2" };

JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(mStringArray));
```

Beware that code is written offhand so consider it pseudo-code.

Comment: Is arrays.asList necessary? Even tough JSONArray has no constructor with String[] as parameter the following code works fine for me:
`String[] strings = {"a", "b"};
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(strings);
System.out.println(json.toString());`

Comment: Both ways work, but at least in Android, JSONArray(strings) isn't supported until API 19

Comment: The way that works in the current version of java is:

new JSONArray().addAll(Arrays.asList(mStringArray))

Comment: No, "arrays.asList" is not necessary; otherwise, it becomes the original array in a new array of one single entry.

Answer (score 40):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("blah");
list.add("bleh");
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

This is only an example using a string arraylist

Comment: Yep! Doesn't seem to work on normal String arrays though as they are not part of the Collection ( http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html )? But if all else fails you can just run a for loop for that.

Comment: Try passing `Arrays.asList(stringArray)`

Comment: `asList()` does not seem to work as I am having this problem right now

Answer (score 8):

example key = "Name"  value = "Xavier" and the value depends on number of array you pass in

```
 try
      {
      JSONArray jArry=new JSONArray();
      for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
       JSONObject jObjd=new JSONObject();
       jObjd.put("key", value);
       jObjd.put("key", value);
       jArry.put(jObjd);
      }
      Log.e("Test", jArry.toString());
      }
 catch(JSONException ex)
     {

     }
```

Answer (score 7):

you need external library

```
 json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar

List mybeanList = new ArrayList();
mybeanList.add("S");
mybeanList.add("b");

JSONArray jsonA = JSONArray.fromObject(mybeanList);
System.out.println(jsonA);
```

Google Gson is the best library http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 7):

This is the correct syntax:

```
String arlist1 [] = { "value1`", "value2", "value3" };
JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(arlist1);
```

Answer (score 5):

For a simple java `String` Array you should try

```
String arr_str [] = { "value1`", "value2", "value3" };

JSONArray arr_strJson = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(arr_str));
System.out.println(arr_strJson.toString());
```

If you have an Generic ArrayList of type String like `ArrayList<String>`. then you should try

```
 ArrayList<String> obj_list = new ArrayList<>();
    obj_list.add("value1");
    obj_list.add("value2");
    obj_list.add("value3");
  JSONArray arr_strJson = new JSONArray(obj_list));
  System.out.println(arr_strJson.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

My code to convert array to Json

**Code**

```
List<String>a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("so 1");
a.add("so 2");
a.add("so 3");
JSONArray jray = new JSONArray(a);

System.out.println(jray.toString());
```

**output**

```
["so 1","so 2","so 3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert ArrayList to JsonArray**
: Like these [{"title":"value1"}, {"title":"value2"}]

Example below :

Model class having one param title and override toString method

```
class Model(
    var title: String,
    var id: Int = -1
){
    
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "{\"title\":\"$title\"}"
    }
}
```

create List of model class and print toString

```
var list: ArrayList<Model>()
list.add("value1")
list.add("value2")
Log.d(TAG, list.toString())
```

and Here is your output

```
[{"title":"value1"}, {"title":"value2"}]
```