# Android Data Object interaction with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

I am working on Android app with webview using javascript. I have an method which is returning Arraylist, i want to access it in my javascript. I know how to handle a single string returning from a method in javascript ,but i want to know about how to handle a Dataobject of arraylist in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a good way to translate Java objects (other than primitives and `String`s) across the Javascript bridge. What you probably want to do is convert your `ArrayList` into a JSON array and then pass the serialized representation over to the JavaScript code. You can then `eval` it or use `JSON.parse` to convert it into a JavaScript array.

Comment: Thanx Femi...Will u please provide me a good resource or documentation to do it...

Comment: Unfortunately I really don't have good documentation: the little I've done with this isn't really something I can share. I'd suggest taking a look at the source for the PhoneGap Android project at http://www.phonegap.com/: they do extensive JavaScript bridge work.

Comment: Array to JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166592/convert-normal-java-array-or-arraylist-to-json-array-in-android