# Send arraylist as request parameter through android

Tags: android

Is there any alternative to send request parameters through android other than `NameValuePair`. I'm trying to send arraylist as request parameter, but `NameValuePair` accepts only string value.

Comment: add more details including code you have written till now.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider sending the ArrayList as JSONArray.

Check this SO post.

[convert ArrayList<MyCustomClass> to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylist-to-jsonarray)

[Convert normal Java Array or ArrayList to Json Array in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166592/convert-normal-java-array-or-arraylist-to-json-array-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

read about JSONObject, JSONArray .. you can convert it to string with toString method and then bring it back to JSONObject, JSONArray passing this String constructor if you receive it from server.

Generally its a standard way of passing complex structures.

Answer (score 0):

Store arraylist in to a string and then send it..

```
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
        contactlist.add("Android");
        contactlist.add("tarnaka");
        contactlist.add("uppal");
        contactlist.add("Prasad");

        String[] contact=new String[contactlist.size()];
        contact=contactlist.toArray(contact);
```