# How to convert Arraylist to Json in Java

Tags: java, json

I have an arraylist, the arraylist holds a bunch of Domain object. It's like below showed:

```
Domain [domainId=19, name=a, dnsName=a.com, type=0, flags=0]
Domain [domainId=20, name=b, dnsName=b.com, type=0, flags=12]
Domain [domainId=21, name=c, dnsName=c.com, type=0, flags=0]
Domain [domainId=22, name=d, dnsName=d.com, type=0, flags=0]
```

My question is how to convert the `ArrayList` to JSON? The data format should be:

```
{  
"param":{  
  "domain":[  
    {  
      "domid":19,
      "name":"a",
      "dnsname":"a.com",
      "type":0,
      "flags":
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166592/convert-normal-java-array-or-arraylist-to-json-array-in-android

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly what you need, but you can use the **GSON** library ([Link](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) for `ArrayList` to `JSON` conversion.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("str1");
list.add("str2");
list.add("str3");
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

Or in your case:

```
ArrayList<Domain> list = new ArrayList<Domain>();
list.add(new Domain());
list.add(new Domain());
list.add(new Domain());
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

If for some reason you find it more convenient, you can also iterate through the `ArrayList` and build a `JSON` from individual `Domain` objects in the list

```
String toJSON(ArrayList<Domain> list) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Domain d : list) {
        sb.append(gson.toJson(d));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I know it's an old comment, but if anyone get stuck at this point:

new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Domain>>(){}.getType());