# Ajax - Get a Business Object list in JSP

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a Ajax call from my JSP and generating a ArrayList of a business object in the servlet. Now I don't know how to iterate the list and populate the BO in JSP.

My code as below:

**Servlet code :**

```
ArrayList<TestBO> ajaxList = new ArrayList<>();
TestBO bo = new TestBO();
bo.setName("Name1");
bo.setAdress("Kolkata");
bo.setMobile("909090000");
ajaxList.add(bo);

bo = new TestBO();
bo.setName("Name2");
bo.setAdress("Delhi");
bo.setMobile("808000000");
ajaxList.add(bo);

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(ajaxList);
out.close();
```

**JSP code :**

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/TestWeb/AjaxServletList',
     datatype:'text',
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
         var values = [];
         values = data;    
     }
});
```

Comment: use json array.. and that's not jsp it's js/jquery

Comment: can you give me an example please

Comment: since you do using ajax you can use json .check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771822/how-to-convert-arraylist-to-json-in-java

Comment: thanks a lot... It works great :)