# I'm trying to convert ArrayList to JSON with GSON, but data get truncated

Tags: android, json, arraylist, gson

I'm trying to convert ArrayList to JSON using GSON. It works perfectly for small data. But when it comes to large ArrayList the converted JSON get truncated.
How can I convert entire ArrayList to JSON?

Here is my code

ArrayList is as below:

```
public class ProductCheckList {
    int id;
    String characteristics;
    String specification;
    String total_subpoints;
    String min = null;
    String max = null;
    String key1 = null;
    String spec1 = null;
    String value1 = null;
    String min1 = null;
    String max1 = null;
    String key2 = null, spec2 = null, value2 = null, min2 = null, max2 = null;
    String key3 = null, spec3 = null, value3 = null, min3 = null, max3 = null;
    String key4 = null, spec4 = null, value4 = null, min4 = null, max4 = null;
    String key5 = null, spec5 = null, value5 = null, min5 = null, max5 = null;
    String key6 = null, spec6 = null, value6 = null, min6 = null, max6 = null;
    String specificationValue;
    String audit_id;
    String vin;
    String user_id;
    String vehicle_id;
    String variant_id;
}
```

Conversion to JSON

```
ArrayList<ProductCheckList> productCheckLists =new ArrayList<>();
String checklist = new Gson().toJson(productCheckLists);
```

Comment: Could you show what do you mean by "truncated" on some example data?

Comment: Truncated in logcat log or actual data? I have to ask this considering my past experience with a similar question.

Comment: You should iterate the arrayList as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771822/how-to-convert-arraylist-to-json-in-java

Comment: @Rohit5k2 getting truncated string in actual data

Answer (score 2):

I used your code , just converted in kotlin (but it's the same) and it worked without any problem

```
   inner class ProductCheckList (
     var id: Int = 0,
     var characteristics: String? = null,
     var specification: String? = null,
     var total_subpoints: String? = null,
     var min: String? = null,
     var max: String? = null,
     var key1: String? = null,
     var spec1: String? = null,
     var value1: String? = null,
     var min1: String? = null,
     var max1: String? = null,
     var key2: String? = null,
     var spec2: String? = null,
     var value2: String? = null,
     var min2: String? = null,
     var max2f: String? = null,
     var spec3: String? = null,
     var min3: String? = null,
     var max3: String? = null,
     var min4: String? = null,
     var max2d: String? = null,
     var key12: String? = null,
     var spec12: String? = null,
     var value12: String? = null,
     var min12: String? = null,
     var max12: String? = null,
     var key2r: String? = null,
     var spec2f: String? = null,
     var value22: String? = null,
     var min245: String? = null,
     var max2455: String? = null,
     var spec355: String? = null,
     var min366: String? = null,
     var max377: String? = null,
     var min3d: String? = null,
     var max3d: String? = null,
     var min4d: String? = null,
     var spec2fdd: String? = null,
     var value22er: String? = null,
     var min245ew: String? = null,
     var max2455w: String? = null,
     var spec355w: String? = null,
     var min366f: String? = null,
     var max377f: String? = null,
     var min3df: String? = null,
     var max3dg: String? = null,
     var min4dg: String? = null
)




 fun checkStackOverflow(){
    val productCheckLists = ArrayList<ProductCheckList>()
    productCheckLists.add(ProductCheckList(1,"pippo","pluto","minnie","topolino", "dog","pippo","pluto","minnie","topolino", "dog"
    ,"pippo","pluto","minnie","topolino", "dog","pippo","pluto","minnie","topolino","topolino", "dog","pippo","pluto","minnie","topolino",
        "topolino", "dog","pippo","pluto","minnie","topolino","topolino", "dog","pippo","pluto","minnie","topolino","topolino", "dog",
        "pippo","pluto","minnie","topolino","pluto","minnie","topolino"))
    }

`
```

What I've noticed is that it puts elements in alphabetical order so maybe for that you think that is truncated. For example element min4dg is not the last one so you could think it is trucanted

```
[{"characteristics":"pippo","id":1,"key1":"pippo","key12":"dog","key2":"pippo","key2r":"topolino","max":"dog","max1":"dog","max12":"topolino","max2455":"minnie","max2455w":"pippo","max2d":"topolino","max2f":"dog","max3":"minnie","max377":"dog","max377f":"topolino","max3d":"pluto","max3dg":"minnie","min":"topolino","min1":"topolino","min12":"minnie","min2":"topolino","min245":"pluto","min245ew":"dog","min3":"pluto","min366":"topolino","min366f":"minnie","min3d":"pippo","min3df":"pluto","min4":"topolino","min4d":"minnie","min4dg":"topolino","spec1":"pluto","spec12":"pippo","spec2":"pluto","spec2f":"dog","spec2fdd":"topolino","spec3":"pippo","spec355":"topolino","spec355w":"pluto","specification":"pluto","total_subpoints":"minnie","value1":"minnie","value12":"pluto","value2":"minnie","value22":"pippo","value22er":"topolino"}]
```

The other possibility is using the following code:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val arrayValues= gson.toJsonTree(productCheckLists).asJsonArray
```

Comment: Thank for reply. It works perfect when ArrayList has less values.
But it truncates data when values are more (let's say 50 entries)

Comment: I've just tried with 60 fields and it works.
Are you refering to fields of object or number of elements in the array?

Comment: I'm referring to no.of elements in the array

Comment: I've just tried with array of 65 elements each elements has 60 fileds and it works.

I've also found another way to do it but the result is the same.

Comment: I edited the answer with the other way to perform the json array