# How to send string array to php?

Tags: java, php, android

I want to perform same as bellow in my android project how can i do it?

Html:

```
<html>
<body>
        <form action="npost" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n1[]" value="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n1[]" value="2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n1[]" value="3">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Php:

```
$s1 = $_POST["n1"];
```

Comment: Can you not just change `params.put("s1"` to `params.put("s1[]"`?

Comment: no "s1[]" not working it will return single data to because it is Map<String,String>

Comment: s1 ???? Use "n1[0]" , "n1[1]" and "n1[2]".

Comment: it will not entertain if u have large data and also automated data to be written to server

Comment: Of course it can work then to. Just make a loop. Very simple.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach to this problem:
First, convert the array to a json ( [Follow This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166592/convert-normal-java-array-or-arraylist-to-json-array-in-android) )

After that, send the json as a normal string to your php, then use `json_decode($yourstring)` to convert the string to a json file.

Read the json file out and loop through it to store as an Array.