# POSTing a array from android to Google apps script

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, android-studio, google-apps-script

I am trying to send an array to google script to put into google sheets.

What I have for the google script:

```
  function insert(e, sheet) {
 
  //var scannedData = e.parameter.sOrder;
  var scannedData = JSON.parse(e.parameter.sOrder);
  var orderLocation = e.parameter.sLocation;
  var d = new Date();
  var ctime =  d.toLocaleString();
  
  sheet.appendRow([scannedData, orderLocation, ctime]);
  
  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput("Success")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);  

  
  
}
```

the results it gives me is:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@5c0b25d1    Shipping    25/07/2020, 22:32:21
```

what it should give me is:

```
0152502243  Shipping    24/07/2020, 18:20:37
```

my code on my apps side:

```
 postDataArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(finalData));
            postDataParams.put("sOrder", postDataArray);

            postDataParams.put("sLocation",orderLocation);
            postDataParams.put("sheetName",sheetName);


            Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());
```

finalData is a String[] that consists of 2 entries.
"Location"
"Data"

if i send finalData[0] as a control then it picks up the first entry, but it gives me this error instead:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@5c0b25d1
```

The google script needs to take either an array straight or convert a string into an array, and I am stuck on this conversion.

so google script must take the array

```
finalData = {"Location","Data"}
```

and convert it into:

```
[Location] 
[Data]
```

Comment: Where does the array come from?

Comment: The for-loop does create this `{Shipping; 0152502243}` as `dData` doesn't it?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, dData is just where it is stored, according to the sources the {Shipping; 0152502243} is the format in which google sheets interpret thestring as an array, but it never sends it through as one.

Comment: No. This `dData += "; "` adds `;`. Isn't it ?

Comment: @TheMaster in a sense, that was the only way i could think of to compile the list into a string, and then separate it with the semicolons.

Comment: Why do you need to send arrays?why not just send as  plain strings? Java arrays are different from JavaScript arrays.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5166592/

Comment: @TheMaster This is good, but its not solving my problem, i got to the point where data gets sent to the google script, but it isn't resolving the string back into an array. I will edit my question appropriately. because i need a way for google script to convert what it has received into an array.

Comment: You need to send it as a json string from Java. You can then parse it apps script. Json is kind of standard for sending data.

Comment: @TheMaster I see, is there then a related post showing how to receive the json in the google script?

Comment: Should be easy..``JSON.parse(e.parameter.sOrder)``

Comment: @TheMaster Cool, so i got it to accept the JsonArray, but i am getting: '[Ljava.lang.Object;@4d3987f3' as an output

Comment: Update your question by adding the latest code and the error.

Comment: @TheMaster The question is now updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending and receiving structured data, it is preferable to [send](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5166592/) and [receive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as json.

[Sheet#appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) accepts a single argument of type array. This array should not be a nested array. Try

```
sheet.appendRow(scannedData);
```

or

```
sheet.appendRow([...scannedData, orderLocation, ctime]);
```

or

```
sheet.appendRow(scannedData.concat([orderLocation, ctime]);
```

Comment: You truely are the master! it worked when i sent scannedData on its own, I truly do appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a doPost(e)

```
doPost(e) {
  ...
  var scannedData = e.parameter.sOrder;
  var arr ="{"+ scannedData+"}";
  var orderLocation = e.parameter.sLocation;
  var d = new Date();
  var ctime =  d.toLocaleString();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid')
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([arr,ctime]);
```

Comment: Please update your question so it's a little clearer.  [mcve]

Comment: I updated the question, I hope that i made it a  bit more clear.